# Query to retrieve recursively parent child nested list joining to another two tables MySQL-PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, mariadb-10.4

I've 3 tables and I want to joint them based on the following conditions. My first table is called `components` it has the main parent and it has a sub-component called `sub_compnents` which holders the `component_id` from the parent. The third table is called `activities` and this table has a parent-child relationship with itself and has a `sub_component_id`.  `parent_activity_id` is expected to hold the parent activity id and `is_activity` is a boolean and I used to store for extra values as such to show me labels such as  `1.1.1`, `A` if it values is `false` to show or group related activities together by `parent_activity_id`, and `is_activity` is `true` then roman numbers i. ii, iii, so on will used on the loop time.

my tables design is as follow

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_component`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_component` (
  `component_id` int NOT NULL,
  `component_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `component_description` text NOT NULL,
  `created_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_component`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_component` (`component_id`, `component_name`, `component_description`, `created_time`) VALUES
(1, 'Integrated Rangeland Development and Management (IRDM)', 'Integrated Rangeland Development and Management (IRDM) Integrated Rangeland Development and Management (IRDM)', '2021-10-05 10:29:18'),
(2, 'Livelihood Improvement & Diversification (LID) ', 'Livelihood Improvement & Diversification (LID) ', '2021-10-05 10:51:17'),
(3, 'Improving Basic Services & Capacity Building (IBSCB)', 'Improving Basic Services & Capacity Building (IBSCB)', '2021-10-05 10:51:17'),
(4, 'Project Management, Monitoring and Evaluation', 'Project Management, Monitoring and Evaluation', '2021-10-05 10:51:17');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_llrp_activity`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_llrp_activity` (
  `llrp_activity_id` int NOT NULL,
  `llrp_activity_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `llrp_activity_description` text,
  `unit_id` int NOT NULL,
  `budget` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `male_beneficiary` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `female_beneficiary` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `youth_beneficiary` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `llrp_activity_created_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `llrp_activity_update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `component_id` int NOT NULL,
  `sub_component_id` int NOT NULL,
  `is_activity` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `parent_llrp_activity_id` int DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_llrp_activity`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_llrp_activity` (`llrp_activity_id`, `llrp_activity_name`, `llrp_activity_description`, `unit_id`, `budget`, `male_beneficiary`, `female_beneficiary`, `youth_beneficiary`, `llrp_activity_created_time`, `component_id`, `sub_component_id`, `is_activity`, `parent_llrp_activity_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Consultative Capacity Building and Formulation of Project Documents', 'Consultative Capacity Building and Formulation of Project Documents', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, '2021-11-17 12:36:36', 1, 1, 0, 0),
(2, 'Training of Practitioners/Staffs, Community Consultations, Formulation, Validation, Publication and Familiarization of RMIPs', 'Training of Practitioners/Staffs, Community Consultations, Formulation, Validation, Publication and Familiarization of RMIPs', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, '2021-11-19 07:55:39', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(3, 'Training on  Physical and Biological Soil and Water Conservation Activities', 'Training on  Physical and Biological Soil and Water Conservation Activities', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, '2021-11-19 07:57:03', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(4, 'Refresher Trainings for TF Members and Local Facilitators ', 'Refresher Trainings for TF Members and Local Facilitators ', 3, '20000000', 200, 150, 100, '2021-11-19 09:38:11', 1, 1, 1, 2),
(5, 'Community Consultations, Training, Planning (Formulation of RMIPs) & Familiarization Activities', 'Community Consultations, Training, Planning (Formulation of RMIPs) & Familiarization Activities', 1, '', 0, 0, 0, '2022-01-21 11:09:34', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(6, 'Refresher Trainings for TF Members and Local Facilitators ', 'Refresher Trainings for TF Members and Local Facilitators ', 4, '20000000', 200, 150, 100, '2022-01-21 11:10:37', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(7, 'Formulation and Consolidation of RMIP', 'Formulation and Consolidation of RMIP', 1, '', 0, 0, 0, '2022-01-21 11:11:33', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(8, 'Formulation and Consolidation of RMIP', 'Formulation and Consolidation of RMIP', 3, '2000000', 200, 200, 100, '2022-01-21 11:12:49', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(9, 'Validation Workshop of RMIP ', 'Validation Workshop of RMIP ', 1, '3000000', 100, 2000, 100, '2022-01-21 11:13:28', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(10, 'Development of National Level RMIP Summary Document', 'Development of National Level RMIP Summary Document', 3, '10000', 100, 100, 20, '2022-01-21 11:14:18', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(11, 'Publication of RMIP Documents (Copies)', 'Publication of RMIP Documents (Copies)', 4, '2000', 100, 100, 100, '2022-01-21 11:19:14', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(12, 'Familiarization Workshop of RMIPs for Regional & Federal Stakeholders', 'Familiarization Workshop of RMIPs for Regional & Federal Stakeholders', 3, '50000', 90, 90, 50, '2022-01-21 11:20:20', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(13, 'Training on SWC Practices at Cluster Level', 'Training on SWC Practices at Cluster Level', 3, '6000', 100, 100, 20, '2022-01-21 11:22:13', 1, 1, 0, 3),
(14, 'Training on Water Spreading Weir and Gully Control Practices  at Regional Level', 'Training on Water Spreading Weir and Gully Control Practices  at Regional Level', 3, '30000', 100, 100, 10, '2022-01-21 11:22:59', 1, 1, 0, 3),
(15, 'Training of DAs on SWC Practices at Woreda Level', 'Training of DAs on SWC Practices at Woreda Level', 3, '25000', 250, 300, 150, '2022-01-21 11:26:08', 1, 1, 0, 3),
(16, 'Training on  Rangeland Management, Forage Development and Nursery Site Establishment Practices', 'Training on  Rangeland Management, Forage Development and Nursery Site Establishment Practices', 1, '', 0, 0, 0, '2022-01-21 11:33:57', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(17, 'Training on Forage Development & Management at Cluster Level ', 'Training on Forage Development & Management at Cluster Level ', 3, '233000', 200, 250, 150, '2022-01-21 11:37:06', 1, 1, 0, 16),
(18, 'Training of DAs on Forage Development & Management  at Woreda Level', 'Training of DAs on Forage Development & Management  at Woreda Level', 3, '100000', 100, 60, 50, '2022-01-21 11:38:21', 1, 1, 0, 16),
(19, 'Trainings on GPS, GIS and Remote Sensing Applications ', 'Trainings on GPS, GIS and Remote Sensing Applications ', 1, '', 0, 0, 0, '2022-01-21 11:39:41', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(20, 'Training on GPS, GIS and Remote Sensing Applications at Federal Level', 'Training on GPS, GIS and Remote Sensing Applications at Federal Level', 3, '60000', 10, 30, 5, '2022-01-21 11:40:27', 1, 1, 0, 19),
(21, 'Training on GPS, GIS and Remote Sensing Applications at Regional Level', 'Training on GPS, GIS and Remote Sensing Applications at Regional Level', 3, '600000', 130, 120, 60, '2022-01-21 11:41:01', 1, 1, 0, 19),
(22, 'Training on GPS, GIS and Remote Sensing Applications at Cluster Level', 'Training on GPS, GIS and Remote Sensing Applications at Cluster Level', 3, '60000', 200, 120, 30, '2022-01-21 11:41:42', 1, 1, 0, 19),
(23, 'Procurement of Handheld GPS Receivers ', 'Procurement of Handheld GPS Receivers ', 4, '560000', 120, 2000, 2000, '2022-01-21 11:42:49', 1, 1, 0, 19),
(24, 'Trainings to Capacitate Regional  & Cluster Level Project Staffs & Implementing Partners', 'Trainings to Capacitate Regional  & Cluster Level Project Staffs & Implementing Partners', 1, '', 0, 0, 0, '2022-01-21 11:43:42', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(25, 'Training on Strategic Investment Guidelines at Regional Level (7 Per Region & 3 Per Cluster)', 'Training on Strategic Investment Guidelines at Regional Level (7 Per Region & 3 Per Cluster)', 3, '7500000', 60, 50, 10, '2022-01-21 11:44:38', 1, 1, 0, 24),
(26, 'Training on Contract Administration and Construction Supervision  at Regional Level ', 'Training on Contract Administration and Construction Supervision  at Regional Level ', 3, '6000', 30, 50, 25, '2022-01-21 11:45:25', 1, 1, 0, 24),
(27, 'Training on Planning, Study and Design of Low-Traffic Volume Roads and Crossing Structures at Federal Level ', 'Training on Planning, Study and Design of Low-Traffic Volume Roads and Crossing Structures at Federal Level ', 3, '25000', 120, 60, 30, '2022-01-21 11:46:17', 1, 1, 0, 24),
(28, 'Training on Planning, Study and Design of Headwork, Water Supply and Irrigation Structures (Surface and Groundwater Sources) [Carried-over activity from 2013] at Federal Level ', 'Training on Planning, Study and Design of Headwork, Water Supply and Irrigation Structures (Surface and Groundwater Sources) [Carried-over activity from 2013] at Federal Level ', 3, '25000', 30, 20, 12, '2022-01-21 11:47:21', 1, 1, 0, 24),
(29, 'Training on 3ds Max for 3D Design, Modeling & Rendering Solution and Quantity Surveying, Rate Analysis & Cost Estimation at Federal Level ', 'Training on 3ds Max for 3D Design, Modeling & Rendering Solution and Quantity Surveying, Rate Analysis & Cost Estimation at Federal Level ', 3, '3560000', 50, 30, 10, '2022-01-21 11:47:59', 1, 1, 0, 24),
(30, 'Training on Project Management (Cost, Time & Quality Management) with the Help of Project Management Software at Federal Level ', 'Training on Project Management (Cost, Time & Quality Management) with the Help of Project Management Software at Federal Level ', 3, '356000', 20, 10, 5, '2022-01-21 11:48:33', 1, 1, 0, 24),
(31, 'Consultative Meeting & Performance Review', 'Consultative Meeting & Performance Review', 1, '', 0, 0, 0, '2022-01-21 11:48:54', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(32, 'Quarterly Consultative Meeting and Performance Review Sessions at Federal Level', 'Quarterly Consultative Meeting and Performance Review Sessions at Federal Level', 3, '25000', 20, 10, 5, '2022-01-21 11:49:56', 1, 1, 0, 31),
(33, 'Consultative Meeting with Federal & Regional Engineers on the Performance & Progress of Strategic Investments on a Quarterly Basis ', 'Consultative Meeting with Federal & Regional Engineers on the Performance & Progress of Strategic Investments on a Quarterly Basis ', 3, '3000', 30, 20, 10, '2022-01-21 11:50:42', 1, 1, 0, 31),
(34, 'Establish and Strengthen Rangeland Management Councils/Committee at Cluster and Woreda Levels', 'Establish and Strengthen Rangeland Management Councils/Committee at Cluster and Woreda Levels', 1, '', 0, 0, 0, '2022-01-21 11:51:11', 1, 1, 0, 1),
(35, 'Establishment of Rangeland Management Councils/Committees at Clusters ', 'Establishment of Rangeland Management Councils/Committees at Clusters ', 3, '300000', 30, 30, 10, '2022-01-21 11:52:20', 1, 1, 0, 34);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_sub_component`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_sub_component` (
  `sub_component_id` int NOT NULL,
  `sub_component_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sub_component_description` text NOT NULL,
  `sub_component_created_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_component_update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `component_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_sub_component`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_sub_component` (`sub_component_id`, `sub_component_name`, `sub_component_description`, `sub_component_created_time`, `component_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Integrated Rangeland Management Planning – IRMP', 'Integrated Rangeland Management Planning – IRMP', '2021-10-06 22:20:48', 1),
(2, 'Supporting Strategic Investments', 'Supporting Strategic Investments', '2021-10-06 22:20:48', 1),
(3, 'Conflict Management & Secure Access to Key Resources', 'Conflict Management & Secure Access to Key Resources', '2021-10-14 09:16:58', 1),
(4, 'Enhancing Pastoral and Agro-Pastoral Production System', 'Enhancing Pastoral and Agro-Pastoral Production System', '2021-10-14 09:18:19', 2),
(5, 'Promoting livelihood Diversification & Market Access', 'Promoting livelihood Diversification & Market Access', '2021-10-14 09:18:34', 2),
(6, 'Provision of Basic Social Services and Infrastructure', 'Provision of Basic Social Services and Infrastructure', '2021-10-14 09:18:57', 3),
(7, 'Institutional Capacity Building Sub Component', 'Institutional Capacity Building Sub Component', '2021-10-14 09:19:06', 3),
(8, 'Knowledge Management, Research and Policy Support sub component', 'Knowledge Management, Research and Policy Support sub component', '2021-10-14 09:19:18', 3),
(9, 'Community Contribution ', 'Community Contribution ', '2021-10-14 09:19:29', 3),
(10, 'Project Management', 'Project Management', '2021-10-14 09:19:59', 4),
(11, 'Planning, Monitoring and Evaluation', 'Planning, Monitoring and Evaluation', '2021-10-14 09:20:27', 4);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_component`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_component`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`component_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_llrp_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_llrp_activity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`llrp_activity_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_sub_component`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_sub_component`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sub_component_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_component`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_component`
  MODIFY `component_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_llrp_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_llrp_activity`
  MODIFY `llrp_activity_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=36;
COMMIT;
```

I want to achieve for each component list with its sub-component and activity with its parent first and child next nested; some have child activities have 2/3 parents and others may have 1 or even no parent at all;  as follows

[image]

hope guys, now you understand what I want to achieve. any tip or code will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive cte to retrieve the activities and join them to sub-components and components. Storing the full hierarchy in your adjacency list would make things easier but I am assuming there are other dependencies within your schema.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE activities AS
(
    SELECT sub_component_id, llrp_activity_id, llrp_activity_name, 0 AS depth, CAST(llrp_activity_id AS CHAR(200)) AS path
    FROM tbl_llrp_activity
    WHERE parent_llrp_activity_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a1.sub_component_id, a1.llrp_activity_id, a1.llrp_activity_name, a2.depth+1, CONCAT(a2.path, ',', a1.llrp_activity_id)
    FROM tbl_llrp_activity a1
    JOIN activities a2 ON a2.llrp_activity_id = a1.parent_llrp_activity_id
)
SELECT c.*, sc.*, a.*
FROM activities a
JOIN tbl_sub_component sc ON a.sub_component_id = sc.sub_component_id
JOIN tbl_component c ON sc.component_id = c.component_id
ORDER BY path;
```

**Pet peeves**

1. Avoid calling tables table. `component` or `components` is definitely preferable to `tbl_component`.
2. Avoid prefixing your column names with the table name. `sub_component.description` is easier and clearer than `tbl_sub_component.sub_component_description`.

**UPDATE**

An example using UNIONs instead of joins to get all the components, sub-components and activities. I just realised that component_id is available in the activities table so I removed the unnecessary join in the first of the three UNIONed queries. I have also added column number comments so it is clear what is being UNIONed with what. You will probably need to add where clauses to the UNIONed queries  -

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE activities AS
(
    SELECT
        /* 1 */ component_id,
        /* 2 */ sub_component_id,
        /* 3 */ llrp_activity_id,
        /* 4 */ llrp_activity_name,
        /* 5 */ llrp_activity_description,
        /* 6 */ 0 AS depth,
        /* 7 */ CAST(LPAD(llrp_activity_id, 4, '0') AS CHAR(200)) AS path
    FROM tbl_llrp_activity
    WHERE parent_llrp_activity_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        /* 1 */ a1.component_id,
        /* 2 */ a1.sub_component_id,
        /* 3 */ a1.llrp_activity_id,
        /* 4 */ a1.llrp_activity_name,
        /* 5 */ a1.llrp_activity_description,
        /* 6 */ a2.depth+1,
        /* 7 */ CONCAT(a2.path, ',', LPAD(a1.llrp_activity_id, 4, '0'))
    FROM tbl_llrp_activity a1
    JOIN activities a2 ON a2.llrp_activity_id = a1.parent_llrp_activity_id
)
(

    SELECT
        /* 1 */ 'activity' AS level,
        /* 2 */ path,
        /* 3 */ component_id,
        /* 4 */ sub_component_id,
        /* 5 */ llrp_activity_id,
        /* 6 */ llrp_activity_name,
        /* 7 */ llrp_activity_description
    FROM activities

) UNION ALL (

    SELECT
        /* 1 */ 'component' AS level,
        /* 2 */ -2 AS path,
        /* 3 */ c.component_id,
        /* 4 */ -1 AS sub_component_id,
        /* 5 */ -1 AS llrp_activity_id,
        /* 6 */ c.component_name,
        /* 7 */ c.component_description
    FROM tbl_component c

) UNION ALL (

    SELECT
        /* 1 */ 'sub-component' AS level,
        /* 2 */ -1 AS path,
        /* 3 */ sc.component_id,
        /* 4 */ sc.sub_component_id,
        /* 5 */ -1 AS llrp_activity_id,
        /* 6 */ sc.sub_component_name,
        /* 7 */ sc.sub_component_description
    FROM tbl_sub_component sc

) ORDER BY component_id, sub_component_id, path;
```

Adding the "No" labelling should be done when building your HTML as this is definitely display logic. There is also no explicit ordering of components, sub-components and activities in the tables so I have assumed ordering based on ids and path.

Comment: the query can't be run on MyQSL Workbench said **'query interrupted'.**, I can give u some sample data but how can I share it with you?

Comment: Your "query interrupted" was masking the real error. The column names have changed between your original CREATE TABLE statements and the updated ones in your question. Make sure the output panel is visible in workbench.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 8.0.27 to develop the system and the server is running using Mariadb 10.4. I've updated the tables with sample data. regarding the rows **table tbl_components** has less than **10 records**, **tbl_sub_components** around **50 records** and **tbl_llrp_activity** will have more than a **1000 records**.  btw I want to show the result on a website so I'm using PHP as serverside scripting to get and display in HTML

Comment: the query is run now and I see more than 170 records, and i see records of other components are joing with non sub_components records. for example, i've send you only records of sub_compoents of component record id 1 and all activities related to sub_component id 1 only. on the result i see component id 5,4,3,2 joins with sub_component id 1, though sub_component_id 1 is only depends on component id 1.

Comment: I have added an example using UNION. Adding an index to parent_llrp_activity_id improves efficiency on the recursive CTE but with such a small dataset it was sub-millisecond either way, in my testing. You can check against the previous row's values to see if you are still in the same component / sub-component.

Comment: thank you so much for everything, u r a genius.